# FastReport+DelphiXE8 Cross-tab, bold rows

Tags: fastreport

Is it possible to bold some rows in the cross-tab in FastReport in Delphi?
I create a report using MS SQL procedure dynamically.
For certain values (specifically ID) in a row I would like to rapidly thicken the entire line.
The number of rows is constant, but the number of columns for the data are not.
The example bellow, when Salary=Ben then row for Ben should be bolded.
[Example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0UXg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use in report's script:

```
procedure Cross1OnPrintRowHeader(Memo: TfrxMemoView; HeaderIndexes, 

HeaderValues, Value: Variant);
begin
  if Value = 'Ben' then Memo.Font.Style := fsBold;                                                                                                 
end;

procedure Cross1OnPrintCell(Memo: TfrxMemoView; RowIndex, ColumnIndex, CellIndex: Integer; RowValues, ColumnValues, Value: Variant);
begin
  if RowValues[0] = 'Ben' then Memo.Font.Style := fsBold;                                                              
end;
```